# Resume online Test Application in .Net

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I am creating a online Exam application in mvc4. How can i apply resume technique in my application. Means after attempting some in day one, user will login in my system and proceed further from the last attempted question . What are the ways i can store the data during resume ?

Comment: what you have tried till now?? post your code!!

Comment: I am tried with sql storage and webstorage of HTML5

Comment: I mean have you done any coding?? If yest post it here so that people can understand it clearly...

Comment: No no  not right now . I was just thing the best ways for it.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a check if the user has answered all of the questions that the test has. If yes, return result page for example, if not return the next question. Simple as that. Since you dont provide any code I cant help you any further.